# finding path using prolog

Tags: path, prolog, path-finding

I want to find whether there is a path from one point to another or not.

For example, `2 -> 4 -> 7`
             `1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 9`
              `5 -> 1 -> 6 -> 8`

these are the path.
I want to write a predicate path(Start, End), and arcs are represented by a set of arc(From, To) facts.

For example, when path(1, 7) is given this must return true.
             when path(6, 1) is given this must return false. because arcs are directed.

Answer (score 1):

1. If there is an arc between X and Y, then Path=arc(X,Y). That is,
   if arc(X,Y) then path(X,Y)). Or, in Prolog this is:

   path(X,Y,[arc(X,Y)]) :- arc(X,Y).
2. Otherwise, if there is an arc between X and some other node Z, and there is
   a path from Z to Y, then there is a path from X to Y too. That is,
   if arc(X,Z) and path(Z,Y) then path(X,Y). In Prolog this is:

   path(X,Y,[arc(X,Z)|P]) :- arc(X,Z),path(Z,Y,P).

Taken from [this](http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~markov/ccsu_courses/prolog.txt) site.

You could also bundle this into one predicate that simply takes a list of arcs and recursively searches for a path

Comment: This seems true but my path will take only 2 parameters. This path is taking 3 parameters.

Comment: Just extend it with path(From,To) :- path(From,To,Path)

Comment: Yes, this one lets you input a list of arcs. If you want to skip that parameter just define the arcs within the document and extend it like Alexander said

Answer (score 0):

Try to answer splitting the problem in elementary problems.

```
path(From, To) :-
  arc(From, Intermediate),
  path(Intermediate, To).
```

But, do you see where path should stop? And if there are cycles, what happens?

What's miss it's the trivial case, stating that `path(X, X)` it's always true. Add to above rule:

```
path(To, To).
```

Maybe it's clearer if we write a single rule, using If Then Else

```
path(From, To) :-
  (   From \= To
  ->  arc(From, Intermediate),
      path(Intermediate, To)
  ;   true
  ).
```